# How can I rename a folder name using grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

There is a folder say...

**vendor/jquery-1.10.0**

How can I write a grunt task such I can strip off the version off of the dependency name?

i.e I want just **vendor/jquery**

This can be the last task the the grunt list of tasks. I **do not** want to do this while copy is happening.

Comment: What about creating a symlink to point to it? Might be less hassle.

Comment: dunno what that is..never done it

Answer (score 0):

The first results on searching for [grunt rename folder](https://www.google.com/search?q=grunt+rename+folder) show the [`grunt-contrib-rename`](https://github.com/jasonlam604/grunt-contrib-rename) npm.
You may want to check that out.

I don't know what is your flow, but maybe you should consider making a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) instead of renaming the folder every time, as @meder suggested.
Either you create one manually and don't care about renaming your folder any more, or use [grunt-contrib-symlink](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-symlink) to create it as in a task.